# Restrict the user to select only one radio button [ Select one radio button and de-select all ]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bunch radio button with common name and different ID's and different values. By default, it should work like when you select 1 radio button, other one need to deselect, since its having common name. But here its working as user can select multiple radio buttons which shouldn't happen. Need to restrict the user to select only 1 radio button option Can anyone help here please?

```html
<div class="radio-button-label-radio" id="vendorsRadio">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="my" id="Finvu" label="" value="10001" class="vendors">
    <div class="column large-6 medium-5 small-5 vendorsText">Finvu</div>
  </li>
</div>


<div class="radio-button-label-radio" id="vendorsRadio">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="my" id="Reliance" label="" value="100002" class="vendors">
    <div class="column large-6 medium-5 small-5 vendorsText">Reliance</div>
  </li>
</div>

<div class="radio-button-label-radio" id="vendorsRadio">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="my" id="Amazon" label="" value="100004" class="vendors">
    <div class="column large-6 medium-5 small-5 vendorsText">Amazon</div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not use the same ID multiple times (vendorsRadio) An Id should always be unique.

Comment: Yes i removed that ID vendorsRadio and kept empty value. But still problem exist. Please help

Comment: Also `Need to restrict the user to select only 1 radio button option` ain't that working? You have the same name on the Inputs so it should work.

Comment: Nope i can select both the radio butons at the same time. It should not happen. Any javascript/Jquery help with this?

Comment: It's working fine, you can not select multiple radiobuttons with the same name. It's the whole point of radiobutton (instead of checkbox). If the problem persist in your project/site, it's something else that is wrong with the page, could be invalid html.

Comment: Is there any hack with JS/Jquery to select only 1 radio button?

Comment: @user2349508 You don't need a hack, as you see in your code example here, everything is working. So go back and try to find what is wrong with your page that is breaking the rest of the site. You could start by validating the html here https://validator.w3.org/